# Apache server not receving http request

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I have created a new http website. The site was working properly. Then I converted it to https (using  certbot certificate). After converting, I am not able to load the website without explicitly mentioning https in the url (https://example.com and https://www.example.com is *working*, but example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is *not working*). In the latter case (without mentioning https in the url), the request result in a timeout. `curl -I` has the exact same behavior.

I checked the apache access log and it seems like the request is not even reaching the server.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue. I am hoping that this answer will help someone.

The problem was that ubuntu firewall was blocking the request (I accidentally reset ufw and only enabled https). I checked `tcpdump -nnSX port 80` to see if the server was receiving the request on port 80. When I found that the server was actually receiving the request, but the apache was not, I suspected that ufw was blocking it.